# Bash Script to list files within a directory

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, batch-file

I need to create a bash script that will send out an email with the files contained in a specific directory. The script will get the directory location. (ie. `./script.sh /backups/daily`).
Once the script is executed it will send out an email with the list files contained in `/backups/daily`. The email will also include the size of each file in GB and the date when the file was created.
I'm very new with linux. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6):

Crude, but this should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -lh "$@" | mailx your@email.com -s "listing of $@"
```

I used `mailx` here, but the right mail command will depend on your system, and it might need more flags, for example for authentication. It could be `mail` or `sendmail`, or something else.

In `ls -lh`, the `-l` is for long listing which includes the size and the date. The `-h` is for "human readable" format of file sizes, so that for example instead of 81883042 (bytes) you would see `78M` as the size.

Answer (score 2):

If what you need is a listing of the contents of your directory, with size and modification time, then `ls -lh /backups/daily` is likely what you need.

If you need to automate this to run daily, use `crontab -e` to set up a job with cron. Run `man crontab` for more info. The crontab you edit could contain something like the following:

```
#<Minute> <Hour> <Day_of_Month> <Month> <Day_of_Week> <Command>
05 01 * * * ls -lh /backups/daily
```

As by default, cron mail the output of job to the user, this would email YOU a listing every night at 1:05am.

You can pipe the output of this listing into a mail command in order to send to others. Edit and try this on the command line, then when it's working, add it to your crontab.

```
ls -lh /backups/daily | mail -s "backups contents for `date -I`" toaddress@example.com
```

It's possible to tailor the output of ls if needed. A simple (and overly simplistic) filter for the ls output is to chop off the left hand side of each line:

```
$ ls -lh | cut -c32-

98M Jan 14 14:01 meb.20140105-030003.img
98M Jan 14 14:01 meb.20140106-030003.img
$
```

This is overly simplistic because the width of the left hand portion (32 in my case) will change based on user and group names.  If these are constant for you, then adjust the number, and the overly simple would be good enough.

Comment: This is great. But how do you think I could tailor the output to only show the file_name, Size and date created.
This is what i'm getting now:
    `total 1.5T`
    `-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 769G Jan  5 13:55 meb.20140105-030003.img`
    `-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 755G Jan 12 13:49 meb.20140112-030003.img`
But I would like:
    `meb.20140105-030003.img 769G Jan  5 13:55`
    `meb.20140112-030003.img 755G Jan 12 13:49`

Comment: With ls options alone, to my knowledge it's not possible to get just the size and date. So you need to either filter the ls output, or write a script from scratch. A simple filter would be to pipe the output of ls(1) through cut(1) to chop of the left hand side of each line - I'm adding an example of this to the answer above. Other filters could be done with awk, sed, perl, etc.